# Docker Port forwarding doesn't call css and images

Tags: web-applications, docker, port, magento2

I have setup port concepts in docker to access my container  magento2  to locally connected another system.

This is Docker Container Setup:

```
  docker run -it -d --name containerName -h www.myhost.net -v /var/www/html -p 3000:80 --net mynetwork --ip 172.11.0.10 --privileged myimagename
```

then, Execute the Container:

```
      docker exec -it containerName bin/bash
```

volume path **/var/www/html** with in the volume path i write one **index.html** file and  access to anoter locally connected system its working fine.

```
   hostmachineip:3000
```

After I installed magnento2 in my container with in volume(/var/www/html),

Then test Its working for me.But **Doesn't call css and images.**

```
  hostmachineip:3000
```

But Magento2 Working file in host machine and also port forwarding working file, Because if i call **hostmachineip:3000/index.html** It working fine.

But: if I call **host machine** its working file,

```
 hostmachineip:3000
```

Its redirect to right server, **show magento2 home page with css and images.**

**remote machine** **only not calling css and images.**

Configuration File:  /etc/nginx/site-available/default (server 172.10.0.30)

```
# nginx Confoguraration

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name www.xxxxx.net  xxxx.net;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_log;


        root  /var/www/html;

        location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        }

        # Deny access to specific directories no one
        # in particular needs access to anyways.
        location /app/ { deny all; }
        location /includes/ { deny all; }
        location /lib/ { deny all; }
        location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
        location /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
        location /report/config.xml { deny all; }
    #    location /var/ { deny all; }

        # Allow only those who have a login name and password
        # to view the export folder. Refer to /etc/nginx/htpassword.
        location /var/export/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
        autoindex on;
        }
     # Deny all attempts to access hidden files
        # such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, etc...
        location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
         access_log off;
         log_not_found off;

     }

        # This redirect is added so to use Magentos
        # common front handler when handling incoming URLs.
        location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        # Forward paths such as /js/index.php/x.js
        # to their relevant handler.
        location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }



       # my proxy Configuration 



       # pass the PHP scripts to FPM socket

       location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT  /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        # send bad requests to 404
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        include  fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Loadbalancer Machine Conf file:

```
    upstream backend {
       ip_hash;
       server 172.10.0.30 weight=5;
       server 172.10.0.40 weight=2;

    }


    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  chennaihousing.net  www.chennaihousing.net;

       location / {

        proxy_pass http://backend;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;

        }


    }
```

include /etc/nginx/proxy_params File:

```
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    client_body_buffer_size 1m;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 256 16k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
```

Why? magento 2 need php support for install in hostmachine, So, Remote Machine also need same Support?. or Any think i miss in this Configuration? Suggest Me How to resolve this problem.

Comment: Its not a docker problem, check your php/magento installation

Comment: @Farhad  yes, this is not a docker problem, Because port forwarding working file, But Magento working fine in host machine.

Comment: Post your Dockerfile

Comment: @Alkaline  I pulled docked image form docker hub follow this link https://hub.docker.com/r/mageinferno/magento2-nginx/~/dockerfile/  this docker image i pulled.

Comment: @Alkaline I update my question..

Comment: remove this line in your proxy config `location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
       }`

Comment: @Alkaline  I update my question in magento site  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137344/magento-2-have-any-port-forwarding-restriction  check this. Now also same problem.